# Why is it possible to send a password reset email to external provider with Firebase AUth Api?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am currently developing an angular+ionic app. Everything is working ok but I got a question with the forgot password workflow: **sendPasswordRestEmail -> user clicks link -> user fill form -> user submit form -> password and oobCode send**  with the firebase auth api, which I am accessing through angular fire package.

As I said everything is working as intended. The only "issue" I see is that firebase not only sends password reset email to user that created their account with an email/password but also users that are using an external provider like Google ( sign in with google). I havent test login with Facebook at this point but it is happening with google provider. I just want to make sure if this is the intended workflow or something may be wrong... a bug or something? before I post an issue on github, because even though the user can "change its password" when using an external provider, it is having no effect on their external account(gmail account) which of course should have no effect.

Comment: If you think there is a bug, just go ahead and file it with your steps to reproduce, and how that differs from the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

[Sending a password reset email](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#send_a_password_reset_email) from Firebase allows the user to reset the password on their **Firebase Authentication** account. It has nothing to do with the password they may have with any social provider associated with that account.

Comment: thanks for your reply but what is the point for changing a password of a user that used google account to login? It does not matter if I change the password or not the user will always be able to login using the google provider or please explain if my thought is worng. either way thanks for the link.

Comment: If you don't want to provide a password for Firebase Authentication for this user, don't offer the password reset option to them, or direct them to the password reset page of the auth provider they used instead of calling the Firebase API to send a password reset email.

Comment: Just did @Frank van Puffelen and again thanks for your explanation but imho password reset should be used only with email/password user  accounts and not with providers since there is not actual effect on the user account itself...

Comment: That's what I meant: if you don't want to allow password reset for social accounts, don't enable that feature in your app for social accounts.